# vector tiles server

Tags: server

For my new application I'll have to start a vector tile server. I followed [this](https://github.com/tilezen/vector-datasource/wiki/Mapzen-Vector-Tile-Service) tutorial and started such on my old laptop for tests. I would like to know best hardware recomendations for this type of server as there aren't any clear informations about this in Google. Are they the same as for standard OSM server?
I expect high usage (more than 1000000 users).

Comment: 1 million users? I'd recommend getting someone else to host it (like AWS, for example) unless you want to spend a lot of money on servers, your internet connection, and spend all of your time doing server and network maintenance.

Comment: Oh, sorry but I don't know if you understand me. I want to rent server from for example OVH. It is maybe because of not clearly asked question, sorry.